# About View, background, Bitmap and scaling

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a view (LinearLayout) that would fill the whole screen and then load some custom background image (bmp, png, jpg). During run time I would like to peek pixel and certain coordinates for their color. Since there are many different devices I have to support different resolutions. My solution is to have one image for background and let it be scaled to proper screens size. The problem is, although the image fills the whole screen as it should, the background bitmaps are scaled to false size. This prevents me to check pixel colors in bitmap, since my coordinates return the false pixel from bitmap.

I have the following layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewWithBackground"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

In res/drawable I have background_320x480.png. This image should be scaled to screen size.

In the onCreate event of the activity I do the following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewWithBackground = findViewById(R.id.viewWithbackground);





//the problem is that the width and height of the bitmap are not correct. Following log entries show sizes
    Log.d(TAG, "viewWithBackground - width: " + viewWithBackground.getWidth() + ", height: " + viewWithBackground.getHeight());
    Log.d(TAG, "viewWithBackground.getBackground() - intrinsicWidth: " + viewWithBackground.getBackground().getIntrinsicWidth() + " intrinsicHeight: " + viewWithBackground.getBackground().getIntrinsicHeight());
    Log.d(TAG, "((BitmapDrawable)viewWithBackground.getBackground()).getBitmap() - width: " + ((BitmapDrawable)viewWithBackground.getBackground()).getBitmap().getWidth() + ", height:" + ((BitmapDrawable)viewWithBackground.getBackground()).getBitmap().getHeight());
}
```

In example: Device display size is 480x800. Image in res/drawable is 32x x 480, Bitmap and BitmapDrawable are 480x720. It does not make sense.

My question: How to get the background Bitmap in the same pixel size as it is displayed on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

1. If device display is 480x800 and you're not using full screen theme height of you're application window will be 800 - height of notification bar
2. Drawable class has a `getBounds` method witch returns rectangle where content of drawable will be drawn

Comment: 1. I use the whole screen. No notification bar visible.
2. A getBounds() method does not matter. Underlying background bitmap of a view is of wrong size, even though it is correctly rendered on the screen. Therefore I cannot probe the pixel color at specific coordinates.